# Qt standard project and examples stopped building

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, qtgui, qdialog

Qt project suddenly stopped building. So as new just created empty projects based on QDialog or examples.  Cleaning, rebuilding not helping.

Log of key errors:

```
/Users/dmitrytolstov/Workspace/Qt521/5.2.1/clang_64/lib/QtWidgets.framework/Versions/5/Headers/qdialog.h:117: 
error: unknown type name 'QDialog'  
Q_DISABLE_COPY(QDialog)

/Users/dmitrytolstov/Workspace/Qt521/5.2.1/clang_64/lib/QtWidgets.framework/Versions/5/Headers/qdialog.h:117: 
error: C++ requires a type specifier for all declarations 
Q_DISABLE_COPY(QDialog)

/Users/dmitrytolstov/Workspace/Qt521/5.2.1/clang_64/lib/QtWidgets.framework/Versions/5/Headers/qdialog.h:117: 
error: unknown type name 'QDialog'

/Users/dmitrytolstov/Workspace/CC++/QtStuff/NewDiaproj/dialog.h:10: 
error: unknown class name 'QDialog'; did you mean 'Dialog'?
class Dialog : public QDialog

/Users/dmitrytolstov/Workspace/CC++/QtStuff/NewDiaproj/dialog.h:10: 
error: base class has incomplete type
class Dialog : public QDialog

/Users/dmitrytolstov/Workspace/CC++/QtStuff/NewDiaproj/main.cpp:8: 
error: no member named 'show' in 'Dialog'
w.show();

7 errors generated.
make: *** [main.o] Error 1
18:46:36: Process «/usr/bin/make» exit with code 2.
```

Seems like something happened with qdialog.h or something. By the way project on QMainWindow  works fine.  I didn't do anything. Tried to reopen QtCreator, reboot computer. 
I use Mac OS X and Qt 5.2.1

Any example provided by QtCreator or empty project based on QDialog. For example:
**dialog.cpp:**

```
#include "dialog.h"

Dialog::Dialog(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent)
{
}

Dialog::~Dialog()
{
}
```

**dialog.h**

```
#ifndef DIALOG_H
#define DIALOG_H

#include <QDialog>

class Dialog : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Dialog(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~Dialog();

};

#endif // DIALOG_H
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "dialog.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    Dialog w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

**NewDiaproj.pro**

```
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2014-04-20T19:31:45
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = NewDiaproj
TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp\
        dialog.cpp

HEADERS  += dialog.h
```

Comment: Is it Qt itself or some example project on top of Qt? If it is the latter, could you please show your code?

Comment: Please show your main function, too, where you use this class.

Comment: Do not post your code as an answer, edit your question.

Comment: @ddriver: he already did before your comment :)

Comment: Show also your .pro file generated by QtCreator, please. Also, why do you have `#include "ui_dialog.h"` if it is not used anywhere?

Comment: Are you sure your QDialog header from Qt is not corrupted? Your code works fine for me on Archlinux with Qt 5.2.1.

Comment: I was trying to launch it with UIForm. Without it's still not building

Comment: Please reinstall Qt to see if it solves the problem. It seems your Qt installation is corrupted. Before that, you could try the command line without QtCreator, although it probably does not make a difference.

Comment: @LaszloPapp It seems to be all right. How to check if it is?
How it could get corrupted if I didn't edit it? As I sad it worked about an hour ago. And all examples were fine.

Comment: It can get corrupted by any accidental or "vis major" action. When you say "it seems to be all right", you mean it works from console, but not from QtCreator?

Comment: @LaszloPapp I reinstalled it, and it works now. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the fact that your files work fine for me on Archlinux with Qt 5.2, I think your `QDialog` file in the Qt installation got corrupted by some accidental or "vis major" action.

Reinstall it cleanly and then it should just work.